# android application that allows text and voice communication between devices on a same LAN

Tags: java, android, chat, lan, wifip2p

i want to develop an android application that allows people on the same wifi network to text and call each other. i looked around and found a few theories which suggested setting up a server client network.i want the devices on the network to scan other devices with the application installed and initiate a chat. i have been using desktop version of such applications which includes outlook messenger, LAN Messenger and a few other and want to apply the same logic to mobile devices. 
i have basic knowledge of java to a point where i had to develop a Point Of Sale Application for a store. I need some pointers, a starting point on how this can be achieved and what protocols i have to research to do so.

Comment: have you tried [Peer-to-Peer framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Peer-to-Peer framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) ? ..

I am developing a similar app right now, however I am not sure about voice call (although, android support SIP) but I am heading toward messaging ..

Comment: where are you with the application?  i used the p2p service to and rtp stream to transmit audio but it is limited to a known ip address. how did you go about discovering peers that have the same application installed.